# Query for Product name search

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a Mysql Database which have product details in a table.I need to search product details by using a query.

Eg:When i type "Dosa" in the name search entry, it should be display "Dosa",Masala Dosa","Ghee Dosa" etc form product table.I used following query.But it is not usefull.

"SELECT productname FROM `productmaster` WHERE productname LIKE 'DOSA%' ORDER BY productname".
It will list Dosa only.Kindly help in this regard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from productmaster where productname like '%DOSA%'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a wildcard `%` on *both* sides of the search term:

```
SELECT productname
FROM productmaster
WHERE productname LIKE '%DOSA%'
ORDER BY productname
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $name = $_Post['name'];`

 $sql ="SELECT ID, DemoNeme1, DemoName2 FROM tableName WHERE  DemoNeme1 LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR DemoName2  LIKE '%" . $name  ."%'";`
```

try this code

Comment: Good advice for easy SQL injection while assuming that this is a PHP question. I really hope that's not the way you write code!